# Apache authentication except localhost

Tags: apache, authentication

I need to apply HTTP auth just in public use of website, but I don't apply it on my localhost. This is the `.htaccess` that I think should work. But it doesn't work - it still asks me for user/pass.
What am I doing wrong?

```
SetEnvIf Remote_Addr ^127\.0\.0\.1$ develmode
<IfDefine !develmode>
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "ADMIN"
    AuthUserFile /path/to/.htpasswd
    Require valid-user
</IfDefine>
```

`mod_setenvif` is enabled of course.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3908592/ht-access-ip-restriction-and-htpasswd


try that

Comment: Have you tried `SetEnvIf Remote_Addr ^127\.0\.0\.1$ develmode=yes`

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You need to look at the `order` and `satisfy` keywords. Working example from my website is below. First we tell that we accept either the IP or USER. Then we define htpasswd file path and that we accept any valid user from that file. Finally we define which client IP addresses can access our web without auth (we deny all other IPs, so that they must auth via htpasswd).

```
# permit by USER || IP
Satisfy any
# USER
AuthUserFile /var/www/munin/.htpasswd
AuthGroupFile /dev/null
AuthName "Password Protected Area"
AuthType Basic
require valid-user
# IP
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from 11.22.33.
```

Comment: And let there be no space after the `,`! Apache gives a 500 error if you do `deny, allow`.

Answer (score 28):

In **Apache 2.4**, `allow`, `deny` and `satisfy` are not used anymore, IP address restriction is also done with `require` now:

```
AuthUserFile /path/to/.htpasswd
AuthName "Restricted Access"
AuthType Basic
Require ip 127.0.0.1
Require valid-user
```

If any of the "Require" directives are fulfilled, the request is allowed. If you want to require both, group them in a `<RequireAll>` block.

For restriction to local access you can use the special syntax `Require local` instead of `Require ip 127.0.0.1`

**Read more:** http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_authz_core.html#require