# Basic HTTP authentication except for localhost with Node using Express

Tags: node.js, express, basic-authentication

I am trying to set up authentication for a Node app using Express for clients that are not running on localhost.

Basically, I have an RPi running Node and I'm using Chromium for the GUI of the device. The problem is that you can just type in the IP address to the device from any browser on the network and it will serve up the same content. This is desired in some cases, but I want to password protect it.

This is my setup using `express-basic-auth`:

```
const express = require('express'),
      basicAuth = require('express-basic-auth');

const app = module.exports = express();
const server = require('http').createServer(app);

// Hook Socket.io into Express
const io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

// Configuration
app.use( basicAuth(
{
  users: { admin: 'secret' },
  challenge: true
}))

app.use( express.static('./my_path/') );

// Socket.io Communication
io.sockets.on('connection', require('./modules/socket'));

// Start server
server.listen(3000, () => console.log("Express server listening on port %d in %s mode", server.address().port, app.settings.env));
```

This works, however, I don't want authentication for localhost.

I can get the host from a request like this:

```
app.use( ( req ) =>
{
  debug( req.headers.host );
})
```

I don't know enough about Node and Express to put it all together.

Maybe there is something with `express-basic-auth` that I'm missing or different authorization middleware that I can use.

Comment: It looks like it can be done fairly easily when using Apache: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8854909/apache-authentication-except-localhost?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up just using `basic-auth` and set the `WWW-Authenticate` response header.

```
const express = require('express'),
      basicAuth = require('basic-auth');

const app = module.exports = express();
const server = require('http').createServer(app);

// Hook Socket.io into Express
const io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

// Configuration
app.use( ( req, res, next ) =>
{
  // Require authentication when the connection is not from localhost.
  if ( req.headers.host == 'localhost:3000' )
    return next();

  var authentication = basicAuth( req );

  if ( authentication && authentication.name == 'admin' && authentication.pass == 'secret' )
    return next();

  res.set('WWW-Authenticate', 'Basic');

  return res.status(401).send();
})

app.use( express.static('./my_path/') );

// Socket.io Communication
io.sockets.on('connection', require('./modules/socket'));

// Start server
server.listen(3000, () => console.log("Express server listening on port %d in %s mode", server.address().port, app.settings.env));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
// Configuration
(req, res, next) => {
  if(req.headers.host != 'localhost')
    app.use({
      users: { admin: 'secret' },
      challenge: true
    });
  next();
}
```

Change 'localhost' to whatever req.headers.host states when a localhost attempts to use the website.

The triple dots in the basicAuth() represents all the rest of the code you have there. next() is used to tell the code to keep going.

It helps to visualize if every request that hits the backend "falls" through setup file. Every thing you add to this file operates like another thing the request is falling through.

Comment: Where would I put that code? I've tried passing that to `app.use()`, but then the page doesn't load. Looks like the server just doesn't respond.

Comment: I missed the next() function. It tells the code to continue. You should replace the configuration code with this.

Answer (score -1):

I think the easiest solution would be to have a web server in front of your application manage the HTTP authentication.  Then when you are local you can bypass the webserver and directly hit the application.

https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/security-controls/configuring-http-basic-authentication/

Otherwise you are going to have to write code to check if the inbound request is from your local device or not, probably by checking the ip address on the request and comparing it against your currently assigned one.